# How to pass additional parameter to $http callback in following format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arguments

To keep my code concise and modular, I am using following way of processing HTTP calls.

From controllers I do:

```
function makeCall(){
    Service.getDetails( url, obj).then(responseFn, errorFn);
}
```

In Service I do:

```
this.getDetails = function(url, obj){
 return $http.get(url);
}
```

Then in Controller I have:

```
function responseFn(){
  //response objct available here by deafult
}

function errorFn(){
//error objct available here by deafult

}
```

In these function I automatically get response and error object. In one case it is fine since I need only the response of `GET` but in one another case I ma calling same method from a different controller, and there I need to use a condition to manipulate the response.

Query: How do I pass a parameter i.e. 'obj' to these callback function from my original `makeCall` function. If I pass two dummy variables to callback function  it do not work. (I expected first argument to be replaced by response and second argument as my argument)

Answer (score 0):

One of your options is extend your returning object, in this case you will have a data access across the controller.

**in your service**:

```
this.getDetails = function(url, obj){
   this.myObjData = obj;    // bind it to your returing object
   return $http.get(url);
}
```

**in your controller:**

```
function makeCall(){
    Service.getDetails(url, obj).then(responseFn, errorFn);  // respond parameter will attach by default, no need to bind it here
}

function responseFn(respond){
    console.log(respond);  // will attach by default
    console.log(Service.myObjData);   // access your data from here
}
```

Hope it help you.